# What calculations are needed for counter-weight balancing on a propeller?

Tags: propeller, weight-and-balance, performance-calculation, constant-speed-propeller, variable-pitch

I am designing a small-scale propeller and i have managed to design on optimized geometry for the blade. However the blade pitch angle adjusts according to different flow speeds so i need to mount counterweight to maintain the balance of the blades. What i need to consider for the calculations? 
Let's say i know already the counterweight shape, mass, and mounting place.

Comment: What do you mean by small scale ? (diameter pitch rpm)

Comment: 40 cm overall diameter, 15 cm blade length, max rpm = 7000

Comment: There are a lot of rc props well suited for those kind of power (2-3 hp) Why would you need variable pitch?

Comment: it is about a project i am carrying out

Comment: For sure, but does it need pitch reverse? Or are you aiming for constant rpm? Lack of informations about the specifications, to build a useful answer. Is it supposed to hover, or cruise at the highest possible speed? What kind of flying device is it?

Comment: Actually the propeller is going to be tested alone in a wind tunnel. Not any flight test would be conducted. However i want to investigate its feasibility on small UAVs (airplanes). So i have already designed the whole propeller system and the only thing remains is to balance the blades spinning of the blades while the propeller will be subjected to different flow velocities

Comment: I don't understand why you need counterweights. Try looking at both Aerovate (passive variable pitch) and Peszke (aeroelastic variable pitch)